# Get value of of chosen items in a dynamically generated Ionic list with checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use checkboxes on a dynamically generated list in Ionic, so that I can get the name of their corresponding labels, I have seen examples that recommend this way:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let player of team.players; let i = index"  >
   <ion-label slot="start" id="{{player}}">{{player}}</ion-label>
   <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="player[i]"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

But this way gives me an error like

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'Joe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update the player to be an object instand of string

```js
  team = {players : [
    {
      name:'player 1',
      selected:false
    },
  ]}
```

template

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let player of team.players; let i = index"  >
   <ion-label slot="start" [id]="player.name">{{player.name}}</ion-label>
   <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="player.selected"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<pre>{{team.players | json}}</pre>
</ion-content>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-j3cbg5)